# How can I check whether an exception has been logged for 30 seconds?

Tags: bash, shell

Background: I'd like to assert that no exceptions are written to a log for 30 seconds. Basically it's a smoke test to see if my application has come up and we haven't introduced any serious bugs.

Requirements: I'd like to do this using a bash script, preferably using common shell utilities. An exception is basically a single line that starts with `!`. There are a lot of other log lines written that are not exceptions.

Questions: How can I do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's one possible solution:

```
timeout 30 tail -F my.log -n 0|grep --line-buffered '^!'|head -n 1
```

. I can then check whether the exit code is 124 or 143 (timed out, don't know why it varies) or 0 (line found). This is my best bet so far. However, the solution doesn't seem to exit very quickly upon exception. I'd love to hear other solutions!

Comment: Do you need the `head -n 1` at all though? As [GNU grep documents](http://www.gnu.org/software/grep/manual/grep.html#Exit-Status) its exit code could be useful enough here?

Comment: If I don't use `head -n 1`, I will always have to wait for it to time out. With `head`, it exits on first occurence. I guess it's a matter of nicety.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming log file will only be updated by program on an event of exception.
You can use the following command:

```
stat log_file_name
```

And you'll get output similar to below. You can run `stat` after 30 sec or so, compare results of current and previous `stat` if you don't see any change in the timestamp then the file has not been modified or otherwise.

```
Access: 2015-03-27 15:22:17.000000000 +0530
Modify: 2015-03-27 15:22:16.000000000 +0530
Change: 2015-03-27 15:22:16.000000000 +0530
```

Comment: Sadly, the log will contain non-exceptions, too... I clarified my question. Thanks, though!